# What essentials are needed to have a small bedroom studio to make music?

Tags: recording, production, beginner

What is some of the best affordable hardware and software for producing music? I just want a basic starter kit that will help me get to know the basics. I only want the absolute essentials for now.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what skills you have already, and what kinds of music you want to make? That would help for a recommendation. For example, if you play guitar, I wouldn't tell you to go out and buy a MIDI keyboard, or if you want to make techno music I might not tell you to get an MPC.

Comment: Look into a guy who runs the recording revolution channel on youtube (he also has a website with the same name). He has tons of great articles on this topic, as well as training on how to use it!

Answer (score 2):

For software, check out DAWs like Tracktion and Reaper.

For hardware, take a look at the AudioBox USB audio interface.

If you're wanting to record MIDI and have a synthesiser that supports the interface, Yamaha UX16.

Comment: Hi Joel, welcome to sound.stackexchange. can you please elaborate on why Zack should use these specfic products?

Comment: They fit OP's criteria of affordable and basic, and cover all bases; audio and MIDI recording, editing and mixing.

Comment: I still use Reaper and an Akai mpk mini using mainly virtual synthesizers. You can go a long way with Reaper.